# unhiding a number of Divs based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

With the following markup, i need a way of revealing the number of Divs, based on what the user inputs into a form input, so if the user enters 5 then divs 1,2,3,4 & 5 are visable but the others are hidden, if they enter 3 then only 1,2 & 3 are visable...

Form Input:

```
<input id="sitesinput" maxlength="3" />
```

Div markup:

```
<div id="inputsite" onChange='site_change()'>
<div id="site1" class="tenth">Site 1<br /><input name="site1" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site2" class="tenth">Site 2<br /><input name="site2" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site3" class="tenth">Site 3<br /><input name="site3" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site4" class="tenth">Site 4<br /><input name="site4" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site5" class="tenth">Site 5<br /><input name="site5" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site6" class="tenth">Site 6<br /><input name="site6" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site7" class="tenth">Site 7<br /><input name="site7" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site8" class="tenth">Site 8<br /><input name="site8" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site9" class="tenth">Site 9<br /><input name="site9" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
<div id="site10" class="tenth">Site 10<br /><input name="site10" type="text" size="3" value="0" /></div>
</div>
```

Please note that the site_change function has nothing to do with what I require here.

Thanks for looking.

B.

Comment: What do you mean by, "revealing the number of Divs"?

Comment: Ah OK - well one thing that is not clear is how the `<div>` elements are hidden in the first place. Is there some CSS rule that hides them?

Comment: yes: <style> .tenth {display:none;) </style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go about this way:-

```
function countAndRun(){
var req = parseInt(document.getElementById("sitesinput").value);
for(i=1;i<=req;i++){document.getElementById("site"+i).style.display="";}
for(i=req+1;i<=10;i++){document.getElementById("site"+i).style.display="none";}
}
window.setInterval("countAndRun()", 1000); // 1 second interval to prevent overload
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What *overload* are you referring to?

Comment: I've often noticed in Google Chrome may not be any other browser that if you run a heavy function with an interval of 1ms, the process spikes and at times hangs also. I'm referring to this overload!

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {

    var divs = document.getElementById('inputsite').childNodes,
        visible = parseInt(document.getElementById('sitesinput').value, 10);

    if (isNaN(visible)) {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0, divsLength = divs.length; i < divsLength; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = (i < visible) ? 'block' : 'none'; 
    }

})();
```

This will loop through all children of `#inputsite` and set their `display` property to either `block` or `none`, dependent on the number entered into `#sitesinput`.

Also, a `div` does not have a `onChange` property, or even `onchange` that can be triggered.

Comment: Alex, re: div event - yes it does!

Comment: @Bifterss No, there isn't. Though you can assign any property to an object, it doesn't mean it will be used, e.g. `window.onWednesdays = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sitesinput").live("change", function () {

   var num = parseInt($("#sitesinput").val());
   for (i = 1; i <= num ; i++)
   { 
      $("#site" + i).hide();

   }


});
```